# python ssl error from gs cloud client MaxRetryError or WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER

Tags: python, ssl, google-cloud-storage

I have a code that runs 24/7 (while true on the main.py file) with multiprocessing (12 workers) that accesses gcloud on a regular basis (listing buckets, downloading etc.)
I dont think its a regular ssl error because I get ssl error only one time throughout a day long run and every subprocess access their own gs client.
I dont really understand why the error happens or how to fix it since the same traceback gives me two types of errors.
Also worked everything until i increased the amount of my workers.

The way i create my client:

```
def get_gs_bucket():
    storage_client = storage.Client.from_service_account_json(JSON_CREDENTIALS_PATH)

    gs_bucket_name = BUCKET_NAME
    return storage_client.get_bucket(gs_bucket_name)
```

the function that's mentioned in the error:

```
def list_gs_dir(prefix=''):
    sleep_random_prevent_gs_over_api_usage()
    return gs_bucket.list_blobs(delimiter='/', prefix=prefix)._get_next_page_response()['prefixes']
```

my error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 601, in urlopen
    chunked=chunked)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 387, in _make_request
    six.raise_from(e, None)
  File "<string>", line 3, in raise_from
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 383, in _make_request
    httplib_response = conn.getresponse()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 1373, in getresponse
    response.begin()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 311, in begin
    version, status, reason = self._read_status()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 272, in _read_status
    line = str(self.fp.readline(_MAXLINE + 1), "iso-8859-1")
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/socket.py", line 586, in readinto
    return self._sock.recv_into(b)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/ssl.py", line 1012, in recv_into
    return self.read(nbytes, buffer)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/ssl.py", line 874, in read
    return self._sslobj.read(len, buffer)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/ssl.py", line 631, in read
    v = self._sslobj.read(len, buffer)
ssl.SSLError: [SSL: WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER] wrong version number (_ssl.c:2309)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 440, in send
    timeout=timeout
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 639, in urlopen
    _stacktrace=sys.exc_info()[2])
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/util/retry.py", line 398, in increment
    raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause))
urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='www.googleapis.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: <url> (Caused by SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER] wrong version number (_ssl.c:2309)'),))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/etl/work_wish/etl/etl/utils.py", line 97, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/etl/work_wish/etl/etl/input_bucket.py", line 119, in get_recent_sstables_group_file_per_node
    sstables_ts_pairs = get_sstables_ts_pairs(node, table_type, last_ts)
  File "/opt/etl/work_wish/etl/etl/input_bucket.py", line 129, in get_sstables_ts_pairs
    gs_path_prefixes = list_gs_dir(prefix=node)
  File "/opt/etl/work_wish/etl/etl/input_bucket.py", line 35, in list_gs_dir
    return gs_bucket.list_blobs(delimiter='/', prefix=prefix)._get_next_page_response()['prefixes']
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/google/api_core/page_iterator.py", line 419, in _get_next_page_response
    method=self._HTTP_METHOD, path=self.path, query_params=params
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/google/cloud/_http.py", line 315, in api_request
    target_object=_target_object,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/google/cloud/_http.py", line 192, in _make_request
    return self._do_request(method, url, headers, data, target_object)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/google/cloud/_http.py", line 221, in _do_request
    return self.http.request(url=url, method=method, headers=headers, data=data)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/google/auth/transport/requests.py", line 470, in request
    **kwargs
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 520, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 630, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 506, in send
    raise SSLError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='www.googleapis.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: <url> (Caused by SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER] wrong version number (_ssl.c:2309)'),))
```